# Why a component from andlabs/ui package is not found

Tags: user-interface, go, andlabs-ui

I am trying following simple code (modified from [here](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/wiki/Getting-Started)) to create a window:

```
package main
import ("github.com/andlabs/ui")
func main() {
    ui.Main(makeMainWin)
}
func makeMainWin(){
    var bmiButton = ui.NewButton("First")
    var otherButton = ui.NewButton("Second")
    //ui.NewVerticalStack does not work; 
    stack := ui.NewVerticalStack(
                ui.NewLabel("Select module"),
                bmiButton,
                otherButton,
                )
    var mainWindow = ui.NewWindow("Hello", 200, 100, stack)
    mainWindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true   } )
}
```

However the code is not compiling and I am getting following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./guiStack.go:14:11: undefined: ui.NewVerticalStack
```

Why it is not able to find NewVerticalStack?
Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NewVerticalStack` is no longer part of the package. You should instead use [`NewVerticalBox`](https://godoc.org/github.com/andlabs/ui#NewVerticalBox):

```
// ...
box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Select module"), false)
box.Append(bmiButton, false)
box.Append(otherButton, false)
var mainWindow = ui.NewWindow("Hello", 200, 100, false)
window.SetChild(box)
// ...
```

Comment: Ok. It had very convenient syntax. Why it is not removed from this page: https://github.com/andlabs/ui/wiki/Getting-Started ? Is there any page where it is documented that NewVerticalStack has been removed?